# powershell renaming folders from list

Tags: powershell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJS2w.jpg)
Ok, so with the batch below, i get a thousands of files contain user id in the file name, match the user id from a txt file, to be moved to a new separate folder named by that user id.

so now i come out with bunch folders named by their user id. now i have the same txt file, but contains first name last name and user id. how can i run a script to find a user id in the txt file, get the matching first and last name and rename that exact folder, so it looks like First, Last and User ID?

Code:

```
{
  $aryfiles = Get-Content "e:\test\users_movetosap.txt"
  $sourcedir = "e:\test"
  $destinationDir = "e:\test\exported"
  $aryfiles | foreach {
    $SourceFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir -Recurse -filter "*$_*"
    $NewFolder = New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $destinationDir -Name
    $_ foreach ($File in $SourceFile) {
       Move-Item -Path $($File.FullName) -Destination $NewFolder
}
```

Comment: code needs to be indented 4 spaces and with 1 blank line before.  in ISE or most editors, highlight your code, tab key to indent. copy.  paste that into your SO question.  shift-tab to put code back where you like it in your editor.

Comment: your sample requires data the you have not provided. a **_picture_** of the required data is NOT in any way adequate. [*grin*] why would anyone want to help you if you **_require them to type in what you already have as text_**?

Comment: ok, understood, how do you want me to provide you the data? as files or copied text?